# Command works on terminal but doesn't work with Ansible module

Tags: ansible

When I run the command `alertmanager -config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml` on the terminal, it runs successfully. 
But when I run the following task against the host

```
- name: run alertmanager
  become: yes
  command: alertmanager -config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml
  tags: alertmanager
```

it fails with the following error

```
fatal: [172.30.1.50]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "alertmanager -config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

I have alertmanager in my path variable and everything seems fine. Am I missing something in the command module?

Comment: have you tried using the full path to the `alertmanager` binary?  So something like `command: /usr/bin/alertmanager -config....`?

Comment: Check your remote "ansible" environment with `shell: env` and check your `PATH` setting. In 99% cases environment is different to your usual interactive shell settings.

Comment: @Zoredache: yes, that change does work. Thanks! I answered my question below.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov yeah I did not update the PATH in Ansible environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the PATH in the remote host but not in the Ansible environment. The following change fixed the issue. (adding the alertmanager path /opt/bin in Ansible)

```
environment:
    PATH: '/opt/bin:{{ ansible_env.PATH }}'
```